# Sample 8x8 patch from 512x512 image in Matlab

Tags: image, matlab

I would like to randomly sample an 8x8 patch from an image that is of size 512x512. Is there a good (a quick and easy) way to do this in Matlab? All I want is an 8x8 matrix that was taken from the image. And I each 8x8 block in the image to be equally likely.

Comment: Randomly choose two numbers between 1 and 507, use these as the indices of the first element of the 8x8 subset... What have you got so far?

Answer (score 2):

Say you have loaded the image using `imread` into a variable called `im` you can then do this:

```
r_X = randi(512-8);
r_Y = randi(512-8);
im_rand = im(r_X:r_X+8, r_Y:r_Y+8);
```

`im_rand` will contain an 8x8 section of your image starting from a corner generated randomly.